# Get a list of data from a dynamic checkbox in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, checkboxlist

need help. I want to get data on toppings from a dynamic checkbox. When a user clicks the order button, i want the data checked in the checkbox to be sent to another activity. As in the following image.

#### From Detail Activity :

[image]

#### To Checkout Activity :

[image]

I've got the topping list using ryclerview on the Detail Activity, so the checkbox indicates that the data is dynamic.

This is my Adapter :

```
class AdapterTopping(val listTopping: List<DataItem?>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTopping.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val checkbox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.ch_box)
        val price_topping = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_price_topping)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_topping,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        if (listTopping != null){
            return listTopping.size
        }
        return 0
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        
        holder.checkbox.text = listTopping?.get(position)?.attributes?.name

        val priceTopping = listTopping?.get(position)?.attributes?.price
        val localID = Locale("in", "ID")
        val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localID)
        numberFormat.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        holder.price_topping.text = numberFormat.format(priceTopping)

    }
}
```

This is my Detail Activity :

```
val btn_pesan = findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.btn_pesan)
        btn_pesan.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(it.context,CheckoutActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        
        ApiConfigFood.getService().getToppings(id).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseFoods>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseFoods>, response: Response<ResponseFoods>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    if (response.body()?.data?.isNotEmpty() == true){
                        val responseBody = response.body()
                        val responseList = responseBody?.data
                        val adapterTopping = AdapterTopping(responseList)
                        rv_topping.apply {
                            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@DetailActivity)
                            setHasFixedSize(true)
                            adapterTopping.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            adapter = adapterTopping
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        // not found data
                    }
                }
                else{
                    // not found data
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseFoods>, t: Throwable) {
                // error server
                Toast.makeText(this@DetailActivity, t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
```

List of toppings for Textview like the second image above

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make your List type non-nullable and your list itself non-nullable so you don't have to do null-checks all throughout your code:

```
class AdapterTopping(val listTopping: List<DataItem>) : //...
```

There are two ways to make check boxes work in an Adapter:

#### 1. Easy but not robust way

Give your DataItem class a mutable property: `var isChecked = false`. In `onBindViewHolder`, update the checkbox state using this property and give the checkbox a listener that updates this value. Since the DataItem class has this property, you can inspect the list contents to determine which items to pass to your next screen as checked ingredients.

```
class AdapterTopping(val listTopping: List<DataItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTopping.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val checkbox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.ch_box)
        val price_topping = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_price_topping)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_topping,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listTopping.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = listTopping[position]
        
        holder.checkbox.apply {
            text = item.attributes.name
            isChecked = item.isChecked
            setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked -> item.isChecked = isChecked }
        }

        val priceTopping = item.attributes.price
        val localID = Locale("in", "ID")
        val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localID)
        numberFormat.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        holder.price_topping.text = numberFormat.format(priceTopping)

    }
}
```

The reason this is not robust is that you are now passing mutable class instances around between classes, changing them in one class and reading the changes in another. This violates the Single Responsibility Principle and can lead to "spaghetti code". Since you are not very well encapsulating functionality, it becomes very easy to introduce bugs as you make changes in your code.

#### 2. Verbose but robust way

The adapter's list property is mutable, but the DataItem class is not mutable. The adapter exposes a callback for when an item is checked that it calls in the change listeners of the check boxes. It is the responsibility of the Activity or Fragment to use this callback to create a new List of DataItems with the appropriate change made. Then it passes this list back to the adapter.

It is very ugly to do this properly with a regular adapter. You should do it with a ListAdapter. You can look up tutorials for how to use ListAdapter.

#### Summary

To start out with, I think you can use the first way until you very firmly grasp the concepts of how an adapter works. In this case, it is not so bad because your list of items passed to the adapter never needs to change length (since it's just a fixed list of ingredients).

To make checkboxes work in an adapter, you have to give them a click listener that fires a callback that the Activity or Fragment can respond to. In that callback,

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've followed my adapter like the example you gave. But now, how can I send values from checkboxes to other activities?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on communicating to other activities?